# MongoDB concat results of 2 lookups within aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to concat the arrays that are the results of 2 lookup operations within a single aggregation pipeline. The results of both lookups are working fine, but the concat of them is resulting null and I cannot figure out why. It could be that Mongo wont acknowledge the lookup results as an array? But that doesnt make sense since I have access to it within the same project stage as arrays...So I dont know really...

The project stage from the pipeline:

```
{
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      visitsTime: 1,
      bracketsTime: 1,
      chartResult: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$visitsTime",
          "$bracketsTIme"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

The current results:

```
[
  {
    "bracketsTime": [
      {
        "date": "04-08-2022",
        "entryHours": 4.25
      },
      {
        "date": "04-10-2022",
        "entryHours": 6.5
      }
    ],
    "chartResult": null,
    "visitsTime": [
      {
        "date": "04-20-2022",
        "visitHours": 1
      },
      {
        "date": "04-10-2022",
        "visitHours": 3
      },
      {
        "date": "04-08-2022",
        "visitHours": 2
      },
      {
        "date": "05-26-2022",
        "visitHours": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is a link for a mongo playground I've been using for this pipeline:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/FKqXozal3n3

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0):

And of course it was a typo....

```
chartResult: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$visitsTime",
          "$bracketsTIme" //should be $bracketsTime
        ]
      }
```